# Nemo-audio-tab in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cinnamon, nemo

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.  I also installed Nemo 3.8.6 from ppa: embrosyn/cinnamon.

In terminal the command: `apt-cache search nemo` gives me the liist of extensions packages.

I installed with `sudo apt-get install` the packages `nemo-media-columns`, `nemo-emblems`, `nemo-audio-tab`.

I got no errors, but... no audio-tab to. Is there an other solution?

Answer (score 1):

The solution came with the upgrade of Nemo to 4.0.6